# How can I keep the trailing slash after choosing a directory from the zsh completion options?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

In *zsh*, when I press tab 2 times to enter the "completion menu", select a directory and press enter, it first adds the chosen directory with a trailing slash to the command, but as soon as I press space to add more arguments, it removes it.

i.e. "rsync foo/" gets changed to "rsync foo " after pressing space.

Is there a way to disable this behaviour?

It forces me to always add slashes manually for commands like *rsync* in particular.

Comment: Just type the /. Or use `unsetopt AUTO_REMOVE_SLASH`.

Comment: This was interfering with autocd. I would type `~/conf/config<ENTER>`, then `i3s<TAB><ENTER>`. It acted like it was about to cd to `i3status/`, then removed the slash and ran i3status instead!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To retain the `/` added after completing directories or symbolic links to directories, turn off the option [`auto_remove_slash`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-AUTO_005fREMOVE_005fSLASH) which is on by default.

```
setopt no_auto_remove_slash
```

For many commands, retaining the trailing slash makes no difference for directories, but causes the command to act on the target directory instead of the symbolic link if the argument is a symbolic link to a directory. For an rsync source argument, a trailing slash causes the directory to be merged into the destination rather than copied to a subdirectory.

Comment: This works great for local paths, but for me it doesn’t affect remote paths like `example.com:some/dir/`. Any idea?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on 5.7.1, if I hit a TAB after a glob, for example, like `cp files/*/*19<TAB>` where the file structure is such that only one folder (and no file) two levels down from `files` ends in `19`. So I want that the glob complete directly to that folder, add a slash, and then let me type the name of a file in that folder. Is that possible?

Comment: @sameers That works for me. Not with the same version, but that's probably not the issue. There are a lot of ways to customize completion and I don't know what settings would affect this.